# Excel VBA worksheet_change event firing only sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a custom filter for a table. This filter is in a cell named `_business_area_dropdown_filter`. The options for this dropdown are created using data validation to show only the unique entries in the column `Business Area`.

The VBA sub I've written works, however it's only fired about 50% of the time. I've checked and `EnableEvents` is turned on. The workbook is `.xlsb` and other VBA code runs fine in it. The code sits in the worksheet code and not a separate module.

Really struggling to understand why it's not firing each time I change the value in the dropdown.

Here is an image of the table I am trying to filter

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Code here:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = ActiveSheet.Range("_business_area_dropdown_filter").Address Then
        
        Dim first_row As Integer: first_row = ActiveSheet.Range("_header_row").row + 2
        Dim team_column As Integer: team_column = Rows(first_row - 2).EntireRow.Find("Team", LookIn:=xlValues).Column
        
        Rows(first_row & ":100").EntireRow.hidden = False
        If Target.Value = "All" Then Exit Sub

        Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(5000, team_column).End(xlUp).row
        
        Dim blanks_selected As Boolean
        blanks_selected = IIf(ActiveSheet.Range("_business_area_dropdown_filter").Value = "(Blanks)", True, False)
        
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = first_row To last_row

            If blanks_selected And Cells(i, team_column - 1).Value = "" Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.hidden = False
            ElseIf Cells(i, team_column - 1).Value = "" Or Cells(i, team_column - 1).Value <> Target.Value Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.hidden = True
            End If
        Next i
        Cells(4, 2).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried adding `Cells(4, 2).Activate` to the end of the sub as I thought for some reason that the cell wasn't updating properly, and needed another cell selecting, in order to make it fire 100% of the time.

Comment: If `EnableEvents` is true, the trigger is called every time. Set a Breakpoint to the top of the code and check what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried turning off EnableEvents at the start of your sub and enable it again at the end? Also, does it matter which ones you select that give you a false-trigger? If you put a break-point at the start of your code, do you always step into it when you change the dropdown?

Comment: I've added a breakpoint on the first line. It is triggered every other time I change the cell. Turning off EnableEvents at the start of the sub, and turning on EnableEvents at the end of the sub makes the code never run.

Comment: The thing that's baffeling me even more is I have the same sub on a different sheet, that's exactly the same and it works every time. I've duplicated the sheet, which also duplicates the code. If I change the dropdown and the table doesn't update, I need to click the dropdown again, and select the same value, and then it updates. Here is an image of the table I'm trying to filter https://ibb.co/NV1PyKN

Comment: It just came to my mind and I don't know if it helps you at all: I once had a similar problem, also with fields that had lookups on it and the sheet where copied from an existing sheet. After searching for > 2 days, I found that everything worked well when I removed a formula like `=Sheet1!MyRange`  - don't ask me why.  I still have a big warning comment in the related code. My advice would be to make a backup of the workbook and than remove everything not really needed for the test from the sheet.

Comment: I've reformatted my code removing references to activeworksheet and it works a bit better. It works everytime when I select "Test" and "Test2", and switch between them, but only seems to work every other time when selecting "All" and "(Blanks)".

Answer (score 0):

Simplified a little:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim first_row As Long, team_column As Long, last_row As Long
    Dim choice, i As Long, v
    
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("_business_area_dropdown_filter").Address Then
        
        choice = Target.Value
        first_row = Me.Range("_header_row").Row + 2
        Me.Rows(first_row & ":100").Hidden = False
        If choice = "All" Then Exit Sub 'no rows to hide
        
        team_column = Me.Rows(first_row - 2).EntireRow.Find("Team", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        last_row = Me.Cells(5000, team_column).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'you already unhid all the rows, so you only need to hide rows here...
        For i = first_row To last_row
            v = Me.Cells(i, team_column - 1).Value
            If Len(v) = 0 Then v = "(Blanks)" 'simplify the logic....
            If v <> choice Then Me.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you find a reason as why it only triggers half of the time in OP's code though? I made a testsheet and both yours as well as OP's code work just fine ?_?

Comment: @Notus_Panda - I'd guess there's some other factor not noted in the question, such as another event procedure or something along those lines maybe...